# Web View running on other than UI thread

Tags: android, andengine, ads, flurry, ui-thread

I am trying to show flurry interstitial but getting following message in debug screen and I am not receiving interstitial on my screen.

> 07-14 15:55:31.390: W/webview(10588): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A
>   WebView method was called on thread 'FlurryAgent'. All WebView methods
>   must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not
>   support use on other threads.

I have followed this tutorial completely :
[Android Integration](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/android/)

At present I am working on AndEngine. As error replying I put my all code in UI thread but result is same.

Here is my code for displaying ads :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);

    // configure Flurry
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(false);

    // init Flurry
    FlurryAgent.init(MainGameActivity.this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);

    mFlurryAdInterstitial = new FlurryAdInterstitial(MainGameActivity.this,
            MY_ADSPACE_NAME);

    FlurryAdTargeting adTargeting = new FlurryAdTargeting();
    // enable test mode for this interstitial ad unit
    adTargeting.setEnableTestAds(true);
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.setTargeting(adTargeting);

    // allow us to get callbacks for ad events
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.setListener(interstitialAdListener);

    mFlurryAdInterstitial.fetchAd();

}

FlurryAdInterstitialListener interstitialAdListener = new FlurryAdInterstitialListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFetched(final FlurryAdInterstitial adInterstitial) {

        adInterstitial.displayAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final FlurryAdInterstitial adInterstitial,
            FlurryAdErrorType adErrorType, int errorCode) {
        adInterstitial.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAppExit(FlurryAdInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onClicked(FlurryAdInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(FlurryAdInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisplay(FlurryAdInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onRendered(FlurryAdInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoCompleted(FlurryAdInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(MainGameActivity.this);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(MainGameActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.destroy();

}
```

So what can I do in this situation?

Comment: tried to use runOnUIThread method?

Comment: @Hellboy, I have used runOnUIThread() method in all section of code but debug message is remain same. Because only that reason I asked here.

Comment: Can you show how did you use it?

Comment: @Hellboy, link for full source code http://pastebin.com/uLCct1hp at present I am directly displaying it.

Comment: You didnt use runOnUiThread in that sample

Comment: I have tested placing UI thread in all flurry section of code. Now you tell me in which section of code I add UI thread. Then I will reply back to you after testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83230/discussion-between-hellboy-and-siddharth).

Comment: I already go for chat section. Please reply in that section :)